# OpenCvSharp only starts with all OpenCvDlls

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm using OpenCvSharp with visual studio 2013. I've installed it through Nuget and it is working fine.

But when I deploy the application it has a DLL directory that has 128M. 128M for x86 and 128M for 64 indeed.
I'm using basically the functions from HighGui and Core. When I remove the DLLs, OpenCvSharp throws an exception when loaded.

I've tried recompile OpenCvSharp without success (this is another question) and even Recompile OpenCV to get smaller DLLs.

Is there any way of loading only the needed DLLs and point out which one can be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of your deployment sounds quite large...
When I create a test project with Nuget package OpenCvSharp-AnyCPU 2.4.10 I get:

- 1.22MB for the net40 assemblies
- 32MB for the x64 dlls
- 29MB for the x86 dlls

OpenCvSharp loads the native dlls on demand (i.e. when the C# code needs the native code) so you *could* remove dlls which your code never uses, but you'd have to check the source or find this out by trial and error.

By default your C# app will build targeting `Any CPU` which means both sets of dlls are needed, but you could set `Platform target: x86` in build properties and just not deploy the x64 dlls.